# How can I pass data to a ShellSection’s ShellContent to reuse the same page for different purposes on a Xamarin.Forms Shell application?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I’m building a [Xamarin.Forms Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) application which provides a flyout and no bottom tabs. The UI is like this:

[image]

The first mockup on the left shows the flyout opened and its items. As you can see, ***Item1*** has its personal page. At the same time, ***Item2***, ***Item3***, and ***Item4*** are grouped both as top tabs and flyout items (I got this result using the `FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems` value on the `ShellSection` element). I want to make the pages with the ***Ipsum***, ***Dolor***, and ***Sit*** titles to share the same page, kind of a “singleton” updated depending on the selected top tab (or selected flyout item). This lets me use a single page instead of creating different ones to host the various contents. On a Xamarin.Forms Shell application, [we can pass data while navigating to pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data), using appropriate properties on the view model of the target page. However, I don’t figure out how to use this with a `ShellSection` element. In my mind, I plan to clear the content of the shared page when navigating to a different tab. To give you an example, let‘s suppose I’m in the ***Item2*** tab, and I click on the ***Item3*** tab (on in the relative flyout item). I plan to:

1. Clear the content of the shared page.
2. Navigate to the new top tab (even if I clicked on the flyout item).
3. Update the shared page with the new content.

I tried using [routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#routes) to pass data to the shared page; however, doing so overrides the default behavior of the application (it navigates to a fullscreen page instead of the tabbed one), so I lose the ability to go to the specific tab. Maybe routes are the way to go, but I don’t know how to manipulate them to navigate the shared page passing data. So far, I wrote this in the `AppShell.xaml.cs` file:

```
var fi = new FlyoutItem    { FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems };
var ss = new ShellSection  { FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems };

foreach (var kind in kinds) {   // "kinds" is obtained from an external service
   var sc = new ShellContent { Title = kind.Name, ContentTemplate = new KindPage(kind.Id) };    
   ss.Items.Add(sc);
}

fi.Items.Add(ss);
ShellItems.Items.Add(fi);
```

Online, I read that I could pass a parameter to the *constructor* of `KindPage`. However, this approach is not well suited for this situation since I need something (that is, cleaning the page to prepare it to host the new tab’s content) when the page *appears*, not when it’s *constructed*. Moreover, this would cause the creation of different `KindPage` objects, one for each tab. Instead, I think a single page would be more well suited. In a nutshell, I would need to specify the `Route` property of the different `ShellContent` elements like this: standard route defined by the inner behavior of Xamarin.Forms Shell **plus** a parameter to let me differentiate the content to be displayed.

So far, overriding the `Route` property with something like:

```
Route = "//KindPage?kind=1";
```

causes the navigation system to obviously bypass the page with the top tabs. Instead, it creates a fullscreen page. I want the top tabs to be maintained. To summarize, I need to define a parameter when navigating to a top tab page (which is kind of a “singleton” page, whose content is reset to host the new content relative to the selected tab). Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: Hi, you could share the xaml code in question, it will be helpful to check whether it's possible. If clicking the flyout item to navigate, it will always open a new  page. It seems there is no way to achieve what your wants.

Comment: Hi. My XAML is almost empty: I set the entire flyout in the code-behind.

Comment: I assume that you are also using MVVM, how about using a shared view model class? Or you can define the object in App.xaml.cs to share the obj globally.